# How to instantiate AudioFormat class in Android?

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

According to Android Developer Docs, AudioFormat class is to be instanced using AudioFormat.Builder class but i'm unable to do so, because AudioFormat.Builder cannot be resolved as a type?

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder().build();
```

Comment: Why didn't you post here your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wasn't a need to instantiate `AudioFormat` prior to Lollipop, it was just a place with a bunch of constants to use with `AudioTrack` and other audio related classes.

`AudioFormat.Builder` was added in Lollipop so you'll need at least API 21 SDK to compile and run code using it. You can still have code with it even if your minSdk is lower than 21, but you'll need to make sure that your code doesn't enter that block on lower API level devices but instead use some alternative methods to achieve whatever it is you want to achieve.

There's more info on [how to support different platform versions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes) on the Android Developers page

Comment: thanks, i've was on API 20, issue resolved by upgrading to API 23

Answer (score 0):

To create a new instance you need to add "**new**" before your `AudioFormat.Builder()`:

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder().build();
```